# error when installing a pod file Cocoapods version 1.9.1

Tags: cocoapods, podfile

*Podfile Contents*

```rb
platform :ios, '11.0'

target 'AVWXKit' do

  use_frameworks!
  pod 'AVWXKit'
end
```

Terminal Input: `pod install`

Error Message:

```
You have either:
 * out-of-date source repos which you can update with `pod repo update`
   or with `pod install --repo-update`.
 * mistyped the name or version.
 * not added the source repo that hosts the Podspec to your Podfile.
```

I have tried repo update to no avail. Any help appreciated 
Using pod version 1.9.1

Comment: Is your target really named `AVWXKit` same as the pod? What happens if you try to name your target differently?

Comment: No joy. I did try that but didn’t work. Opened a fresh xCode project and named it TestCocoa single view app. Changed the pod file to include that as a target name but got the same error. I did try on a different pod and it worked. I am assuming it’s an issue with the AVWXKit in particular

Comment: It seems that pod was never pushed to trunk: when I do `pod search AVWXKit` I get ` Unable to find a pod with name, author, summary, or description matching `AVWXKit`. You can change get the pod using `pod 'AVWXKit', :git => 'https://github.com/JanC/AVWXKit'`

Comment: Awesome thanks Yonat that worked a treat thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that pod was never pushed to trunk: when I do `pod search AVWXKit` I get:

> Unable to find a pod with name, author, summary, or description matching AVWXKit

To work around that, get the pod directly from its repo using:

```rb
  pod 'AVWXKit', :git => 'https://github.com/JanC/AVWXKit'
```